# Book with leads being boy and girl, girl has magic but boy doesn't, later revealed that boy's ancestors killed magic people

Tags: story-identification, books, magic

Boy follows girl (think the girl was kidnapped and brought to the magic world) into the magic world one day and is stuck there for some reason. They are at a magical school (pretty sure its magic highschool) and it's shown that he has little to no magic power but the girl excels. At the end its revealed that the boy comes from a line of magic hunters. Pretty sure it's a series but not certain. Read it in 2009-2010 in a middle school library.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you read this? You said the boy followed the girl into the magic world... what kind of world did he start off in? And what did the 'magic hunters' hunt?

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: Bits of it sounds like *Paraworld Zero* as per https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/235824/23243

Comment: @FuzzyBoots it's has similar plot points but a in this book the boy has no magic in the other world, they are brought to a magical school, and at the end the boy learns about his family's past of magic hunting. Thanks for your help, but they have some differences. Been looking for it for over a year now so any help is appreciated lol

Comment: Hmm... just trying to eliminate another one that came up here (but which I haven't located yet), is there a scene where they come upon, on Earth, a bunch of dissected kids from the magic world, maybe in what seems to be an abandoned barn or warehouse?

Comment: @FuzzyBoots I don't think so, before they go to the magic world it's pretty chill. All of the major plot points take place in the magic realm. Pretty sure they're stuck in the magic school for some reason, can't remember why.

Comment: Hmm... [The Scholomance](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Literature/TheScholomance) has some matching aspects, but Orion hunts magical aberrations (mals), he has magic, and they don't come from another world. :-D

Comment: @FuzzyBoots thanks for trying to help but I think I finally figured it out. ""The Secret of Spellshadow Manor" by Bella Forrest

Comment: @Grace: Congrats! Post that as an answer, but don't forget to explain why it matches.

Answer (score 4):

The answer is ***[The Secret of Spellshadow Manor](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/34425846-the-secret-of-spellshadow-manor)*** (2017) by Bella Forrest, the first book in the *[The Secret of Spellshadow Manor](https://www.goodreads.com/series/202921-the-secret-of-spellshadow-manor)* series.

The plot of the boy following girl to magic school and that the boy has no magic.

From Goodreads:

> What would you do if you spotted a man following a young woman, but no-one else could see him?
>
> Like most sane people, student Alex Webber thought he was hallucinating - perhaps he'd consumed something bad at the party he'd been attending that night, or he was severely overtired. But when he sees the mysterious man following Natalie again the very next day, he can no longer disbelieve his eyes.
>
> Although Natalie denies the man's existence, Alex sees her walking with him down a road in his neighborhood he's never seen before - and can't help but follow. After a bizarre, but strangely short journey, he finds himself standing before a towering iron gate wreathed in gray ivy, behind which looms a decrepit old mansion named Spellshadow Manor.
>
> Spellshadow, with its beautiful yet sinisterly decorated hallways, ever-changing outdoor scenery and very unusual residents... Alex will quickly learn it is a place that is as wondrous as it is deadly.
>
> Especially for a normal person like him.
>
> What if you found yourself recruited to an institute of magic, only to discover you really couldn't do magic?
> What if your enrollment there was all one big, terrible mistake?
>
> If you were at Spellshadow, you'd keep it a secret. A deep, dark, deadly secret...
>
> Because Spellshadow's elusive Head is hiding a secret of his own, one that Alex soon realizes he and Natalie must uncover at all costs if either of them wishes to leave the Manor alive... and before it's too late.

Comment: Glad you found it. Please don't forget to mark your answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons, as per the [tour].